# How to add a graph in titan via cassandra

Tags: database, graph, cassandra, titan

I am running cassandra and titan 1.0.0. I added two table nodes and edges to cassandra. Now I want to make a graph with these two tables and i do not know how to do this. Sorry I searched the titan's document but i could not find my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe this is officially supported by Titan.

You can create a Titan Graph which persists into Cassandra but I don't think you can import a Titan Graph from user defined Cassandra tables.

Titan uses Cassandra as a backend which means that you create the graph through Titan. The graph just happens to be persisted in Cassandra.

A simple example of creating a Titan graph persisted into Cassandra:

```
graph = TitanFactory.open("cassandra:localhost");
v1 = graph.addVertex();
v2 = graph.addVertex();
v1.addEdge("edge-label", v2);
graph.commit();
```

More information on specifying the backend persistence layer (e.g. Cassandra) can be found [here](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/configuration.html)